# Issue with a mouse wiggle effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have written this code to display a small panel when the mouse is over the regions, but I ended up with a terrible "wiggle" effect when I insert an image. How can i fix that?

Have a look at [my codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNyNrY). Relevant excerpt:

```
$('.italia g').mouseover(function (e) {
    var region_data = $(this).data('region');
    $('<div class="info_panel">' + 
        '<img src="  ' + region_data.region_image + ' " >' +
        '</div>'
    ).appendTo('body');
})
.mouseleave(function () {
    $('.info_panel').remove();
})
.mousemove(function(e) {
    var mouseX = e.pageX, //X coordinates of mouse
        mouseY = e.pageY; //Y coordinates of mouse

    $('.info_panel').css({
        top: mouseY - 100,
        left: mouseX - (($('.info_panel').width()/2)+175)
    });
});
```

Comment: I improved the spelling and the formatting of your question. I also added a snippet from your codepen to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the info window is right below your cursor when hovering an area. 
As soon as the infowindow appears, the mouse is triggering the mouseleave event, as it is now hovering the area AND the infowindow, which is above the area.

Check using this:

```
    $('.info_panel').css({
        top: mouseY - 100,
        left: mouseX - (($('.info_panel').width()/2)+175)
    });
```

No wiggle effect anymore.

Comment: thanks :) i almost had ephilepsy from that effect :D